# Catkin hidden files

Tags: ros, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I can see 2 different catkin hidden files in workspace.
.catkin_workspace and .catkin.

As far as I know ros uses .catkin file to mark folder containing packages and executable.

All setup files should be kept in folder having .catkin and .rosinstall. This is the folder which will have "lib" and "share"
directory which gets searched during rosrun or roslaunch.

Actually, I am trying to understand catkin working.

I have some requirements to append to the variables imported by catkin setup.sh.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193072/catkin-hidden-files/) by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to effect the environment in the generated setup.*sh you should use the [catkin_add_env_hooks](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin_add_env_hooks)

Edit:

.catkin_workspace has been recently added as a helper for source management tools. A few topics I found quickly include:

- https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/pull/58
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v9ZEKKNM8W6SXDI5PDiHmdf_PxmhJblCxn-ILey-hUs/edit
- https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/10

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20150/jarvis/) on 2014-09-19**:
Actually I was more curious about how this hidden file gets utilized internally.
I have studied a bit about .catkin file it is utilized in rosrun and roslaunch commands. But wondering if anyone knows about catkin_workspace?